# How to change images in for loop according to each iteration

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to write AJAX call, parse the XML into a Javascript object,
and then display the Javascript object. 
I need to create table. First column will show the list of videos and second column will show the details of particular video. Everything is fine except one thing. I am unable to change the video images and links for each row. I have tried different ways but only first link and image is repeating.

I know there is problem with the logic but I didn't find the right way to do it.

```
function display(resultObj){
 var html = "<table border='0'>";
 html += "<tr><th></th></tr>"+"<br>";
 for(var i=0; i<resultObj.itemArray.length; i++){
   var video = resultObj.itemArray[i];
   html += "<tr>";
   html +="<td>" + "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs' 
   target='_blank'>" + 
   "<img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kbKtFN71Lfs/maxresdefault.jpg' 
   style='width:200px;height:200px;'>" +
   "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjIHB8WzJek' target='_blank'>" + 
   "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/SjIHB8WzJek/0.jpg' 
   style='width:200px;height:200px;'>" +
   "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCXmUi56rao' target='_blank'>" + 
   "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCXmUi56rao/0.jpg' 
   style='width:200px;height:200px;'>" +
   "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko' target='_blank'>" + 
   "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aQxCnmhqZko/0.jpg' 
   style='width:200px;height:200px;'>" +
   "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPcBU0Z2Hj8' target='_blank'>" + 
   "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jPcBU0Z2Hj8/0.jpg' 
   style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>" +;

   html += "<td><br>" + "<p style='color:red;font-family:courier;font- 
   size:25px;'>"      + video.title        +
   "</p>"             + video.channel      + 
   "<br>"             + video.view         + 
   " views"           + "<br><mark>"       +
   video.length       + "</mark>";

   html += "</tr>";
 }
   html += "</table>";
   html += "</table>";
   var resultDiv = document.getElementById("Sresult");
   resultDiv.innerHTML = html;
  }
```

Comment: do you have list of src for images?

Comment: What do you mean by list?

Comment: means in your code you are hardcoding the src of images i.e. why the same img is repeating

Comment: whats the resultobj

Comment: result object is holding information from xml file

Comment: `html +=` table- twice?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by using switch statment:
it is working perfectly fine now.

```
for(var i=0; i<resultObj.itemArray.length; i++){
   var video = resultObj.itemArray[i];
   html += "<tr>";
   switch(i){
   case 0:
       html += "<td>" +
       "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs' target='_blank'>" + 
       "<img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kbKtFN71Lfs/maxresdefault.jpg' 
       style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>";
       break;
   case 1:
       html +=  "<td>" +
       "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjIHB8WzJek' target='_blank'>" + 
       "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/SjIHB8WzJek/0.jpg' 
       style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>";
       break;
   case 2:
       html += "<td>" +
       "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCXmUi56rao' target='_blank'>" + 
       "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCXmUi56rao/0.jpg' 
       style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>";
       break;
   case 3:
       html += "<td>" +
       "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko' target='_blank'>" + 
       "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aQxCnmhqZko/0.jpg' 
       style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>"
       break;

   case 4:
       html += "<td>" +
       "<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPcBU0Z2Hj8' target='_blank'>" + 
       "<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jPcBU0Z2Hj8/0.jpg' 
       style='width:200px;height:200px;'></td>";
       break;

   }
```